# resetting values within LINQ EF query

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

Is there a way to reset a value for grid display within a LINQ query?

For example, the query below sets fullname using two return values, what Id like to do within the query if possible is convert the IsAccountVerified(Byte Column 0 or 1 value) value to true if its 1 and false if it's anything else anything else so that the return carries a string value for IsVerified rather than its database integer value.

```
 Using ctx As New IdentityEntities()
        Dim users = (From d In ctx.useraccounts
                     Join e In ctx.userprofiles On d.Id Equals e.UserAccountId
                     Let fullname = e.FirstName & " " & e.LastName
                     Select New With {
                         d.Id,
                         fullname,
                         d.Username,
                         d.IsAccountVerified
                         }).ToList()

        Return users
    End Using
```

I am currently converting the value in a RowCreated event

```
Public Sub gvSiteUsers_RowCreated(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvSiteUsers.RowCreated
    Dim verifyCol As Integer
    For Each col As DataControlField In sender.Columns
        If col.HeaderText.ToLower().Trim() = "isverified" Then verifyCol = gvSiteUsers.Columns.IndexOf(col)
    Next
    For Each row As GridViewRow In sender.Rows
        If row.Cells(verifyCol).Text = "1" Then
            row.Cells(verifyCol).Text = "True"
        Else
            row.Cells(verifyCol).Text = "False"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

But would prefer to do it within the query if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is unclear. If I understand the d.IsAccountVerified is `string`. May be this can do trick?

```
Dim users = (From d In ctx.useraccounts
    Join e In ctx.userprofiles
       On d.Id Equals e.UserAccountId
    Let fullname = e.FirstName & " " & e.LastName
    Let verified = If(d.IsAccountVerified = 1, "True", "False")
    Select New With
          {
              d.Id,
              fullname,
              d.Username,
              verified
          }).ToList()
```

Comment: Rather than converting the "1" from IsAccountVerified to "True" in a RowCreating event. I want to have the query return "True" in something like Let verified = "True" if d.IsAccountVerfied=1

Comment: IsAccountVerified is a byte column 0 or 1 value

Comment: Do you want to get True as string or Boolean?

Comment: As a string, for use in gridview display

Comment: To use in `GridView` you can use `Boolean` in your binding. Anyway I have updated answer.

Comment: Dim users = (From d In ctx.useraccounts
                         Join e In ctx.userprofiles On d.Id Equals e.UserAccountId
                         Let fullname = e.FirstName & " " & e.LastName
                         Let verified = If(d.IsAccountVerified = 1, "True", "False")
                         Select New With {
                             d.Id,
                             fullname,
                             d.Username,
                             verified
                             }).ToList()